# SQL SELECT with join to exclude items that are already answered by the user

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

So I'm trying to make some kind of webapp quiz.
People will be able to submit their own questions to a database and will be able to take a quiz of 10 random true/false questions.

I want to write an sql select to get questions that are :

1- not uploaded by the logged in user

2- not yet answered by the logged in user

At the moment I have this: ($userid = logged in user id)

```
        public function selectNewRandom($userid){

    $sql = "SELECT `questions`.`id`, `questions`.`quest`, `questions`.`answ`, `questions`.`uploader_id`,`answers`.`item_id`, `answers`.`user_id` FROM `questions` LEFT JOIN `answers` ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id` WHERE `questions`.`uploader_id` != $userid AND (`answers`.`user_id` IS null OR `answers`.`user_id` != $userid) ORDER BY RAND()";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

To get 1 new question that doesn't break the above rules.
My database layout is:

QUESTIONS

-id

-quest

-answ

-uploader_id

ANSWERS

-id

-question_id

-user_id

-answered  (1/0 true false)

This works fine for the first user, he is only getting unique and unanswered questions.. But as soon as a second one logs I think what the command is doing is:
he finds the question_id in the answers table, sees a user_id that is different and stops checking and just allows that question to be returned, even when he also answered the question but the sql never checks. ? so is there maybe a way to check if there is not 1 entry in the answers table that has both the question_id that equals the question id and user_id that equals the $userid (=$_SESSION['user']['id'])

Is there any way to fix this, write another SELECT query or to do it a different way, php maybe?.. (returning an array of 10 questions is also ok..)

[SUMMARY]

It has te check every item with the questions id in the answers table and if one of them has a user_id equal to the logged in user, exclude that item from the result. it works fine if the answered table is empty, showing no more new questions in the end...But if you then log in with another user, no questions that are answered are excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the `answer`'s `userid` in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT q.`id`, q.`quest`, q.`answ`, q.`uploader_id`, a.`item_id`, a.`user_id`
FROM `questions` q
LEFT JOIN `answers` a
  ON q.`id` = a.`question_id` AND a.`user_id` = $userid
WHERE q.`uploader_id` != $userid AND a.`user_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
```

You could also write this with `EXISTS`, but I prefer to use `JOIN` myself.

Basically, what this says is, "Give me all the questions left joined with answers from our user (ignoring answers from anyone else). Then throw away questions uploaded by our user, and throw away questions that have an answer."

That leaves you with what you want -- questions not uploaded or answered by your user.

Answer (score 0):

there  might be  issue  with  creating join using PHP's PDO library, i suggest write simple join query and executed it via my_sqli library. Sometimes binding of parameters arise  such issues.

Comment: I have never experienced any problems with pdo and joins... I think it's doing what it has to do but the SELECT string is a  little wrong.. It has te check every item with the questions id in the answers table and if one of them has a user_id equal to the logged in user, exclude that item from the result. it works fine if the answered table is empty, showing no more new questions in the end...